# How to reference another sheet in the QUERY function?

Tags: parsing, google-sheets, syntax, google-sheets-query

In short, this doesn't work:

```
=QUERY(SHEET1!A:E, "where 'SHEET1'!B contains '"&A1&"'")
```

I am shown:

> unable to parse query string

and I can't work out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use column letters for your query, not a sheet reference. If you are looking for a value in column B, then use `B` in your query.

`=QUERY(SHEET1!A:E, "select A,B,C where B contains '"&A1&"'")`

This will select column `A`, `B`, and `C` where column `B` contains your query. Without the `select` portion, it will select the first column in your range, in this case column `A`.

Comment: @AndrewRidge Happy to hear that!

Answer (score 0):

No way. You need to paste data from `Sheet1 B:B` to the current sheet, and then query it. Use formula:

```
=ArrayFormula('SHEET1'!B:B)
```

or combine data inside query formula:

```
=QUERY({A:E,'SHEET1'!B:B}, "where Col6 contains '"&A1&"'")
```

---

If all the data is placed in one sheet, just use [basic query syntax](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343):

```
=QUERY('SHEET1'!A:E, "where B contains '"&A1&"'")
```